# In python, how to check the full size of a web page, including images, and other embedded elements?

Tags: python, bash, curl, web-crawler, wget

I'm trying to find pages in my network where full download size is too big, let's say, bigger than 10-20MiB.

I already know how to crawl, I need something that will find out the size of everything a browser would be downloading for each page, preferably without actually downloading it, but this condition is of minor importance.

Preferably in python, but if not at least something that I could use inside a bash script (for example curl or wget). I would call that bash script from inside python.

As for more context, in python, right now I'm using requests and beautiful soup for crawling and checking the status response of all the web pages.

Comment: For `wget`, you could use `--delete-after` so it will delete the files when done.  But you do need to download the file (well the html at least) so it can follow links and download the whole page, not just the html file.  Avoid the `-r` option, it will follow links as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```
curl --head https://www.instagram.com
```

it will give this result:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Vary: Cookie, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding
Content-Language: en
Date: Mon, 23 Jul 2018 17:05:14 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=60
Set-Cookie: sessionid=""; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sessionid=""; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sessionid=""; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sessionid=""; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sessionid=""; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sessionid=""; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sessionid=""; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; Max-Age=0; Path=/
Set-Cookie: rur=FTW; Domain=.instagram.com; Path=/
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=Y0WEjvNDGdQXAU7YQoUNsVjSodMT6cOZ; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Mon, 22-Jul-2019 17:05:14 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure
Set-Cookie: mid=W1YKygAEAAGowaTCPQjEP25_NhqF; Domain=.instagram.com; expires=Sun, 18-Jul-2038 17:05:14 GMT; Max-Age=630720000; Path=/
Set-Cookie: mcd=3; Domain=.instagram.com; Path=/
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21754
```

The **Content length** in the last line is the required information.

Comment: I'm seeing some pages don't have a "content-length" in the response. Is it when the page is too dynamic for the server itself to know? Example: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Big_%26_Small_Pumkins.JPG

Comment: it happens when it contains further links, for example the page you shared has few further links one of them being https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Big_%26_Small_Pumkins.JPG now if you do a curl --head for this you will get the complete content lenght

Comment: @fullmooninu I think you can also try a `wget --spyder` your previous link, it will download some files I think , but the good part will be it will get the links to the heavy files on its own along with their size without downloading them, but I must warn you the output is all over the place will be difficult to handle from within a python scriplt